# Virtualization-(Cluster) with KVM/libvirt on top of a FC SAN

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, cluster, storage-area-network, fibre-channel

I'd like to set up a 2-node HA-Cluster based on Ubuntu and KVM running about 30 VM's.
Both nodes are connected to a HP MSA(5TB) via Fibre Channel.
Multipathing's already working and the nodes are able to access the shared storage.

There are two main requirements:

1. Fail-over of running VM's from one node to the other. With downtime.
2. Live-Migration of VM's from one node to the other. Without downtime.

I think there are several ways to achieve this. But which is the best/working?
After some investigation I found solutions/ideas like:

A. Setting up a Cluster with Pacemaker, Corosync, CMAN, DLM, CLVM, GFS2 ...

B. Setting up some Cloud SW like OpenStack, OpenNebula, CloudStack, Eucalyptus ...

C. Or can I somehow put the VM's straight on the LV/LUN and use the KVM/libvirt lock 
manager.

D. ...

At the moment the 30 VM's are running well on a activ/passiv(DRBD) Cluster with Ubuntu, Pacemaker, heartbeat.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You certainly can do c), but why bother? Take a look at [PVE](http://www.proxmox.com/) for example where things are done for you already.

Comment: use A option + pacemaker-remote, in this way, the resources inside the guest are monitored

Comment: @the-wabbit How do the VM's failover in option C? Also the solution need to be free and open source.

Comment: @c4f4t0r Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to monitor individual VM's(only if i have to). In case of a hardware failure of node A all VM's need to start on node B.

Comment: PVE is leveraging [KVM's live migration](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Migration) feature for migrations without downtime. It has an interface to set up LUN configruations which are kept consistent across the PVE nodes in your setup. Take a look - you will like it. PVE is open source and based on a Debian distro, if you have Ubuntu knowledge, you pretty much will feel at home immediately when in shell.

Comment: two hosts aren't a cloud, I'd rule out all the cloud oriented software from the very start. You are trying to build something along the same lines as https://alteeve.ca/w/AN!Cluster_Tutorial_2, though if the system is going to grow, I'd opt for something more serious, like oVirt - it has all the features you asked for and much much more.

Comment: @the-wabbit Thanks I'll take a look at PVE.

Comment: @dyasny You're right. Cloud sw's not what I need. I'll check the the tutorial(takes some days :)). The cluster OS should be Ubuntu or Debian.